# Select a record based on attributes

Tags: smartgwt

I want to select a record in the `listgrid` based on a criteria i provide. How do I do this?

My criteria is:

```
Criteria criteria= new Criteria();
filterCriteria.addCriteria("id", idToSelect);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you filter, other records in the grid will be removed. You can try the following to select only the desired record:

```
int index = myGrid.getDataAsRecordList().findIndex("attribute", "myValue");
myGrid.selectSingleRecord(index);
myGrid.scrollToRow(index);
```